# Python Threading at random returns wrong results

Tags: python, multithreading, rest, python-multithreading

## My Problem

I have been using the python library **Thread**, and it seems to have some issues returning the correct results. When I run the same function e.g. ten times in a row, eight times the results are correct and two times they are wrong.

When the results are wrong, it is because some of the results-dictionarys from the individual calls have been seemingly randomly merged together.

## My Code:

This function makes a session that retries rest calls for certain status codes:

```
# Makes retry sessions
def requests_retry_session(retries=3,backoff_factor=0.3,status_forcelist=(500, 502, 504),session=None):
    """
    Description:
        Creates a session which uses retries
    Input:
        retries (int):  Max number of retries
        backoff_factor (int): Time between retries
        status_forcelist (tuble): Status for which to retry
    Returns:
        session: Requests session which handles different status and connection errors
    """
    session = session or requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        redirect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
    )
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    return session
```

This function makes rest calls for multiple urls:

```
def make_rest_calls(urls, header, store=None):
    """
    Description:
        Processes list of urls
    Input:
        urls (list): List of urls for rest call
        header (dictionary): Dictionary containing credentials
        store (dictionary): Dictionary for collecting results
    Returns:
        store (dictionary): Dictionary with results
    """
    if store is None:
        store = {}
    for url in urls:
        store[url] = requests_retry_session().get(url, headers=header, timeout=5)

    return store
```

This function runs rest calls multithreaded

```
def run_multi_threaded(nthreads, list_of_urls, header):
    """
    Description:
        Runs multiple threads
    Input:
        nthreads (int): Number for threads to run
        list_of_urls(list): List of rest urls
        header (dictionary): Dictionary containing credentials
    Returns:
        store (dictionary): Dictionary with results
    """
    store = {}
    threads = []

    # create the threads
    for i in range(nthreads):
        small_list_of_urls = list_of_urls[i::nthreads]
        t = Thread(target=make_rest_calls, args=(small_list_of_urls))
        threads.append(t)

    # start the threads
    [t.start() for t in threads ]
    # wait for the threads to finish
    [ t.join() for t in threads ]

    return store
```

## Questions

Is this a weakness of the package? Should I use multiple processes instead? Or am I doing something wrong that results in this side effect only some times?

I need to make MANY calls, so it needs to be done multithreaded. The obviously also has to be correct.

Comment: Is this your actual code? `t = Thread(target=make_rest_calls, args=(small_list_of_urls))` should never work because `args` should be a tuple of arguments, i.e. `args=(small_list_of_urls,)`.

Comment: Also, how does `store` get any returning value from your worker threads? You never pass it to the `Thread` constructor either. Please post your real code.

Comment: This is my real code that I read on a long blog about multithreading.

Comment: You mean you copied the code from the blog without modifications? Can you link us to the blog for us to verify what the blog has to say? Again, the code you posted as it is should not work 8 times out of 10, but 0.

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt did you find out the root cause?

Comment: @athos unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2):

As blhsing mentioned, the question is probably not showing some details that could help answering it.

By the description of the results (randomly merged output, only some of the time) it seems like a concurrency problem that could happen when:

1. you **do** pass store as a parameter to make_rest_calls function in the Thread initiation. (This may happen too if the default value of store in make_rest_calls really is '{}' and not None)
2. list_of_urls holds few duplicates in it.

If both of those conditions happen somehow, the outcome might be as described, Because two different threads could potentially try to change the same store entry at the same time.

If this is the situation, the simple solution would probably be to make sure your list_of_urls don't hold the same URL twice. (You might want to use set(list_of_urls) for example.)

It worth mentioning that at least in this usage, there is no use for returning anything in the make_rest_calls function because threads do not return the function's return value. e.g the only way this would ever work is by mutating the input store value, and not by returning anything.

Comment: My list_of_urls does not contain duplicates. I don't understand why make_rest_calls() should not return anything? If "threads do not return the function's return value", what do they then return?

Comment: Nothing. If it would have, where and when would you handle the result? Take a look at [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

Comment: Anyway though, I must admit I agree with @blhsing. This code really doesn't look like something that should run. make_rest_calls should have got the header parameter too. The Thread initiation should have look more like Thread(target=make_rest_calls, args=(small_list_of_urls, header, store))  For this code to make any sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the fact that Threads are not supposed to return anything, and the probably is something at hand with concurrent writing to the `store` dict.

What I would advise is switching from `threading` to `multiprocessing`, which has a slight memory cost (plus time cost of instantiating processes) but the advantage of running actual parallel operations (which you can adjust with some timeout if you want to avoid triggering too many rest calls in a given time frame). Then you can use a `Pool` object and its rather powerful `apply_async` method to set up the full set of tasks (where each task is "make the rest call on this single url") and let it be distributed asynchronously among processes ; you can then use a Queue's `put` method as callback to ensure results collection in the form of tuples, and eventually convert results to dict when you return.

In code:

```py
import multiprocessing

# requests_retry_session is unchanged

# modified based on make_rest_calls:
def make_rest_call(url, header):
    """
    Description:
        Requests a single url. Return its name plus the results.
        Designed for use as a multiprocessed function.
    Input:
        url (str): url for rest call
        header (dictionary): Dictionary containing credentials
    Returns:
        results (tuple): Tuple containing the url and the request's output
    """
    response = requests_retry_session().get(url, headers=header, timeout=5)
    return (url, response)


# full rewrite of run_multi_threaded:
def run_multi_processed(njobs, list_of_urls, header):
    """
    Description:
        Parallelize urls requesting on multiple processes.
    Input:
        njobs (int): Number for processes to run
        list_of_urls(list): List of rest urls
        header (dictionary): Dictionary containing credentials
    Returns:
        results (dictionary): Dictionary with results
    """
    queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(njobs) as pool:
        # Set up the tasks list, asynchronously handled by processes.
        for url in urls:
            pool.apply_async(
                make_rest_call,
                args=(url, header),
                callback=queue.put
            )
        # Wait for all tasks' completion.
        pool.join()
        pool.close()
    # Gather the results and format them into a dict.
    results = {}
    while not queue.empty():
        url, response = queue.get()
        results[url] = response
    return results
```

I hope this helps :-)